# Fewer moves to chessboard edge

Tags: algorithm, chess

Today in an exam I was given a algorithmic problem where I was given the size N*M of a chessboard, and I should determine what is the smallest possible number of moves that a knight can do from the bottom left edge of the chessboard to go to the up right edge. How can that be done?

Comment: Seems like you could use inductive logic with a smaller board to solve this more easily.  Let me think about it.

Comment: For starters, BFS + memoization

Answer (score 2):

A solution using [BFS](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/breadthfirst.html) and [memoization](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/memoize.html):

```
# Memoization
memo = a matrix of NOVISITED of size N x M

# Starting position
# (row, column, jumps)
queue.push((0, 0, 0))

while queue is not empty:
  # Get next not visited position
  row, column, jumps = queue.pop()

  # Mark as visited
  memo[row][column] = jumps

  for each possible move (nrow, ncolumn) from (row, column):
    if memo[nrow][ncolumn] is NOVISITED:
      # Queue next possible move
      queue.append((nrow, ncolumn, jumps + 1))
```

`NOVISITED` can have value `-1` or `null` if we consider the possible distances as a non-negative number `[0,+inf)`.

The minimum number of jumps for each square will be accesible in `memo[row][column]`, so the answer for the top-right corner from the bottom-left will be at `memo[N - 1][M - 1]`.

---

**UPDATE**

Notice that if the matrix is square `N x N`, you can apply symmetry principles.

Comment: This is the best way to go via a programming language.  +1

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can reduce this down to three cases:

1. You have a board with no solution example: 2w * 4h
2. You have a board with a solution of 1: 2w * 3h
3. You have a board that is square and thus has a solution of 4: 3w * 3h

If you have a board larger than these, you can reduce it to one of them by setting the endpoint of one move as the starting point of a larger board.

Example: a board of size 4w * 5h:

```
_ _ _ _
_ _ _ _
_ e _ _
_ _ _ _
s _ _ _
```

where s is start and e is end.

From there, reduce it to a square board:

```
_ 1 e
3 _ _
s _ 2
```

Where it takes 4 moves to reach the end.  So you have 1 + 4 moves = 5 for this size.

I hope that is enough to get you started.

EDIT: This doesn't seem to be perfect as is.  However, it demonstrates a heuristic way to solve this problem.  Here is another case for your viewing pleasure:

```
_ _ _ e
_ 3 _ _
_ _ _ _
_ _ 2 _
_ _ _ _
_ 1 _ _
_ _ _ _
s _ _ _
```

that has 4 moves until the end in a 4x8 board.

Via a programming lanugage, this might be better solved by starting out by mapping all possible moves from your current location and seeing if they match the end point.  If they don't, check to see if your problem is now a simpler one that you have solved before.  This is accomplished via memoization, as a commenter pointed out.

If you are doing this by hand, however, I bet you can solve it by isolating it into a small number of cases as I have begun to do.

Comment: `4 x 8` is solvable in 4 moves.

Comment: Nope 4 moves.  Hmm, do I need to revise something?

Comment: Yep, `4`, typo there. You are implying that it has no solution, am I wrong?

Comment: No, my model isn't perfect as you point out.  Because you can move outside of the bounds you had before, you cannot restrict the board entirely.  Perhaps by allowing an extra row/column in each direction you can cover that.  You can only exceed the tight field by 1 space without being silly and moving *away* from your goal.

Comment: It can be proved that a board with R >= 5 and C >= 5 has always a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could simulate the knight's move using BFS or DFS. Personally I prefer the DFS approach, as it can be implemended recursively. If you have a function `process` which takes as parameters the current x position, the current y position, the rows of the table, the columns of the table and a counter, the the solution will look like that:

```
/* .......... */
process(x-1, y-2, R, C, count+1);
process(x+1, y-2, R, C, count+1);
process(x-2, y-1, R, C, count+1);
process(x-2, y+1, R, C, count+1);
process(x-1, y+2, R, C, count+1);
process(x+1, y+2, R, C, count+1);
process(x+2, y-1, R, C, count+1);
process(x+2, y+1, R, C, count+1);
/* .......... */
```

When you reach your destination, you return the current value of count.

**EDIT:** it can also be solved using dynamic programming. You define `dp(i,j)` to be the best way to reach the square (i,j). So dp(i,j) is equal to:

```
dp(i,j) = min{dp(all squares that can reach (i,j) in one move)} + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the efficient solution.

First, special cases.  If `n = 1` you cannot jump, and the problem is only solvable for `(1, 1)`.  If `n = 2` by inspection there is only one path you can take, and the problem is only solvable if `m = 4k + 3` in which case you need `2k + 1` jumps to get there.  The reverse is true if `m = 1,2`.

Now the general case. A knight has 8 possible jumps, it goes 2 in one direction, and then 1 in another.  The possible directions are `r, l, u, d` (right, left, up, down).  So let `nru` be the number of times it jumps 2 right, then 1 up, and likewise for the other 7 possible jumps.  Then the answer must be a solution to the following pair of equations:

```
n - 1 = 2*nru + nur - nul - 2*nlu - 2*nld - ndl + ndr + 2*nrd
m - 1 = nru + 2*nur + 2*nul + nlu - nld - 2*ndl - 2*ndr - nrd
```

And the number of jumps is:

```
nru + nur + nul + nlu + nld + ndl + ndr + nrd
```

We expect the number of jumps to be as low as possible.  Intuitively if we have a set of numbers that satisfies the top two equations, and we've made the number of jumps low, we shouldn't have much trouble in finding an order to put the jumps which stays inside of the box.  I won't prove it, but this turns out to be true if `2 < n` and `2 < m`.

Thus solve this integer programming problem (solve those two equations keeping the number of jumps as low as possible) and we have our answer.  There are solvers for this, but this particular problem is very simple.  We just do the "obvious thing" to get close to our target, figure out a couple of extra jumps, and it is not hard to prove that this is an optimal solution to the integer equations, and therefore must be the answer to the chess problem.

So what is the obvious thing?  First, if `m < n`, we can just flip the board over, so without loss of generality we may assume that `n < m`.  (The board goes at least as far from you as it does sideways.)  Given that fact, the obvious thing is to jump up-left until you hit the wall, or you hit the diagonal stretching down from the corner that you want.  At which point you progress along the wall or that diagonal towards your target.

If you land directly on the target, you have your best possible answer.

If you went along the wall and missed by 1, it turns out that by converting one of your jumps into a pair you wind up where you need to be.  If you went along the wall and missed by 2 (ie you're one diagonal) then you need to insert 2 jumps.  (Distance shows you that you need at least one more, and a simple parity argument shows that you need at least 2, and a pair of jumps will do it.)

If you went along the diagonal and missed by 1, insert one pair of jumps and you're good.

If you went along the diagonal and missed by 2, then convert a up-right/right-up pair into right-up/right-up/up-left/left-up and you can do it with just 2 more jumps.

If you did not travel along the diagonal but had a up-left, convert that into a right-up/up-left/right-up triplet and again you can do it with just 2 more jumps.

The remaining special case is a 3x3 board, which takes 4 jumps.

(I leave it to you to figure out all of the appropriate inequalities and modulos that picture works out to.)